error 400 when sending an HTTP request to Twitter
When I try to send an HTTP request to get a page to Twitter, I get a 400 error, with the explanation Please switch to a supported browser to continue using twitter.com.
same error when i use jsoup.
same error when I use the web inspector of any browser
Twitter API doesn't interest me at all
Tell me how can I get HTML twitter? Only this site has this error
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
                .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(20))
                .build();

        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create("https://twitter.com"))
                .build();

        HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
        System.out.println(response.statusCode());
        System.out.println(response.body());

I expected to receive the HTML code of the page so that I could pull Elon Musk’s tweets from Twitter in the future. but the response comes with a useless code in the form of a series of errors, a 400 error when connecting and a note "Please enable JavaScript or switch to a supported browser to continue using twitter.com. You can see a list of supported browsers in our Help Center"
if this is important, I connect to Twitter via VPN

if this is important, I connect to Twitter via VPN

You have better to edit your question to add this detail.

Twitter doesn't want you to grab its content randomly. They updated their API model to prevent grabbing data without their consense, so that eg the LLMs won't stress X too much. So X does everything in its power to limit the access to prooved users, and unknown/unsupported Browsers are clients they just don't want.

@Slevin the error from the question seems unrelated to your comment. Unless you could provide some details explaining why it is relevant?

same error when I use the web inspector of any browser  show us this error.

issue resolved using different code. link to continuation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78268126/what-are-the-ways-to-get-elon-musks-tweets-using-http-requests

@aled rzwitserloot gave a perfect answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78268245 - no need for me to do it again

@Mastodont you should close this question since it duplicates your other one and has less information.
